# Isomorphism map keep smoothness?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

Let $E$ be a smooth curve, that is, one dimensional projective variety with dimension one, and Jacobi matrix is non-singular at any point.
And suppose that the map $φ$, which sends $E$ to $E'$, is isomorphism.
Isomorphism means there are two morphism on both direction which composites identity.

Then, can we say that $E'$ is smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

An isomorphism $\varphi$ of varieties induces an isomorphism of local rings $\mathcal O_x\cong \mathcal O_{\varphi(x)}$ at every point, hence an isomorphism of the maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_x\cong \mathfrak m_{\varphi(x)}$ and hence an isomorphism of the cotangent spaces $\mathfrak m_x/\mathfrak m^2_x\cong \mathfrak m_{\varphi(x)}/\mathfrak m^2_{\varphi(x)}.$ It follows that the dimension of the cotangent spaces at $x$ and $\varphi(x)$ are the same, so $x$ is a smooth point of $E$ exactly when $\varphi(x)$ is a smooth point of $E'.$

Comment: Thank you so much !  Is this standard proof ? If you have reference, could you tell me it ?

Comment: How did you induce isomorphic between local rings?

Comment: I don't know if this is standard; I just came up with it. To see the isomorphism of local rings, note that you get an isomorphism of structure sheaves $\mathcal O_E\cong\mathcal O_{E'}$ and hence an isomorphism on the stalks (which are the local rings). Alternatively you get an isomorphism of coordinate rings $k[U]\cong k[\varphi^{-1}(U)]$ where $U$ is any open set in $E',$ and localizing by the maximal ideal of $x\in U$ gives the desired isomorphism.

Comment: How did you get ism between structure sheaves?

Comment: The isomorphism on the structure sheaves is just given by precomposition with $\varphi,$ that is $\varphi^*_{U}:\mathcal{O}_{E'}(U)\to\mathcal{O}_{E}(\varphi^{-1}(U))$ just sends a function $f\in \mathcal{O}_{E'}(U)$ to the function $f\circ \varphi.$